# iOS Persist view transform

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I want to persist position, scale, and rotation of a view.  What is the best way to save each of these attributes?  I know I could save the frame in a CGRect, but will that preserve the scale of my object which has likely changed from the original size?

Is there some certain CGAffineTransform that I can save off that will store all of this data so it can easily be restored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the transform property to query the view for its current affine transform. I.e. `CGAffineTransform transform = view.transform;`

This being said, you'll have to make sure to save the view's frame and any other data necessary to initialize it and restore this before applying the transform.